# Where are drivers downloaded from windows update stored?

Tags: windows-xp, drivers, windows-update

I've got a printer that I periodically have to install on a number of computers... I've lost the driver disk, but the drivers are on windows update. The only problem is that windows update takes forever when I'm updating the printer driver db. I'd like to just toss the driver onto my network storage machine.

So where are they stored if I've already updated via windows update?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have better luck using a third-party piece of software such as [**DriverMax**](http://www.innovative-sol.com/drivermax/).

This will save you having to dig around the `%windir%\SoftwareDistribution` folder looking for cryptically named driver files.  You can simply [export](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/system-administration/copy-windows-drivers-from-one-machine-to-another/) the printer driver to a zipped file or a folder of your choosing and away you go.

I think an even better solution would be to head on over to the manufacturer's website for the printer and download the driver package directly from there.  That way, you'll benefit from any additional features of the printer and have access to detailed settings that *might* not be available using the standard WHQL driver downloaded from Microsoft Update.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply: I've been off sick for a couple of days. I'll check out DriverMax and see if that'll work for what I need. The particular printer driver that is given from the manufacturer is in the form of an exe which also installs other software that I don't want on the workstations.

Answer (score 2):

Download location is

```
C:\Windows\SoftwareDistribution
```

You can also check this link - http://www.windowsbbs.com/windows-xp/46941-windows-update-default-download-folder.html

Answer (score 0):

I know the subject is old BUT :

If you have an EXE, it is possible to open it with a soft like SevenZip.
This way you might find a folder named Driver64 where are the exact thing you are looking for : just the drivers.
You will have to use the "Search for driver on my computer" in Windows to get it installed.

Best regards,

Julien

Comment: I have used Windows Update an got the Folder from it.
It is know on my google Drive so you can copy it :
http://tinyurl.com/HPPRINTERSWUX64